# Rank-based weighted probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose, I have following probabilities which are ranked according to some criterion. I want to take a weighted average of these probabilities such that the ranked 1 probability receives the highest weight and the last ranked probability receives the lowest weight. Can you please suggest what function/method I should use to achieve this?

1. 100%
2. 20%
3. 60%
4. 70%

As a preliminary idea, I have thought of doing something like this:

```
[{100% *(1/1)} + {20% * (1/2)} + {60% * (1/3)} + {70 * (1/4)}] / 4
```

Plainly, I have weighted each probability by the inverse of their respective ranks. Then, divided the sum of weighted probability by the total number of probabilities. Is this acceptable? Any ideas/insights/suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: acceptable for what exactly? Why you divided by $4$ the weighted sum?

Comment: @Masacroso Say, for a statistics/maths/econ journal

Comment: you dont clarified my question. What you did can be acceptable, or not, for anything, depending of your own criteria of "acceptability".

Comment: @Masacroso One of the reasons why I posted this question is, I myself am not too sure about the criteria to use to judge acceptability. Therefore, I requested "insights" and "ideas". Thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: for what reason you want to make this weighted list? what you want from them? what is it utility or idea behind it? The question, as stated, is not answerable because it is not clear what are you asking.

Comment: for sake of clarification: a [weighted arithmetic average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) of elements $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ have the form $$p_1x_1+p_2x_2+\ldots+p_nx_n$$ where $p_k\in[0,1]$ and $\sum_k p_k=1$.

Comment: @Masacroso ok. To put it succinctly, these are the probabilities for a recession in the next 6 months. Each of these probabilities is calculated using different methods. Then they are ranked according to some criterion, say the reliability of each method. Now, I want a rank-dependent weighted probability of a recession in the next 6 months. By the way, I am aware of the weighted average of elements you mentioned. But that was not really my question.

Comment: Your question was, and remains, *unclear.*

Comment: @GrahamKemp which part of my question remains unclear? Sorry, your comment is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many different ways to do this.  However, your set of four weights is not handled correctly. If you want to assign weights proportional to $1,\ 1/2,\ 1/3,\ 1/4,$ you need to do this:

$$
\frac{\{100\%\cdot (1/1)\} + \{20\%\cdot(1/2)\} + \{60\%\cdot(1/3)\} + \{70\%\cdot(1/4))\}}{(1/1) + (1/2) +(1/3)+(1/4)}.
$$

Instead of dividing by the sum of your four weights you divided by the number of weights, which is $4.$ That is not a weighted average. But no matter what you multiply or divide by, it is still what is sometimes called a "weighted sum".

Knowing **which** decreasing sequence of weights to use depends on knowing the purpose. Mathematics alone cannot answer that without more information than what you've given.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael. From one of my previous comments (if you missed it):

"To put it succinctly, these are the probabilities for a recession in the next 6 months. Each of these probabilities is calculated using different methods. Then they are ranked according to some criterion, say the reliability of each method. Now, I want a rank-dependent weighted probability of a recession in the next 6 months." 

Is my purpose still unclear?

Comment: @Anup : It says they are ranked according to the reliability of the methods. Perhaps if we knew something about the reliability of the different methods, more could be done.

Comment: Thank you for being clear here. Honestly, I did not want to over-complicate my question and therefore, just said "reliability of different methods". To be precise, those probabilities were ranked according to a measure called Dynamic Time Warping. Perhaps, you could just refer me to some place where those "different ways to do this" are discussed? That would be of tremendous help. At any rate, thank you for actually answering my question.

Comment: @Anup : Probably you know more about those "different ways" than I do.